# Simple function only works once (show/hide divs) - vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a multi-language website.

I want to be able to press a button, and the display of **all** the (wrapper-content) divs becomes `none`, and only the correct **one** becomes `inline-block`.

It works. But only once. What is the problem? No JQuery please.

**Edit** added some code to html to make it "understandable"

JS (all the functions toSl, toAn etc are the same).

```
function toRu () {
    var lngs, i;
    lngs = document.querySelectorAll(".lng");
    for (var i=0;i<lngs.length;i++){
        lngs[i].style.display="none";
    }
    document.getElementById("ru").style.display="inline-block";
}

document.getElementById("slo").addEventListener("click", toSl);
document.getElementById("ang").addEventListener("click", toAn);
document.getElementById("nem").addEventListener("click", toNe);
document.getElementById("ita").addEventListener("click", toIt);
document.getElementById("hrv").addEventListener("click", toHr);
document.getElementById("rus").addEventListener("click", toRu);
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="lng" id="sl">
<nav>
<div id="lngSpace">
    Language Selector
    <input type="button" id="slo" class="zastave" value="Slo">
    <input type="button" id="ang" class="zastave" value="Eng">
    <input type="button" id="nem" class="zastave" value="Deu">
    <input type="button" id="ita" class="zastave" value="Ita">
    <input type="button" id="hrv" class="zastave" value="Hrv">
    <input type="button" id="rus" class="zastave" value="Rus">
</div>
</nav>
Content of the page in Sl language
</div>

<div class="lng" id="en">
<nav>
<div id="lngSpace">
    Language Selector
    <input type="button" id="slo" class="zastave" value="Slo">
    <input type="button" id="ang" class="zastave" value="Eng">
    <input type="button" id="nem" class="zastave" value="Deu">
    <input type="button" id="ita" class="zastave" value="Ita">
    <input type="button" id="hrv" class="zastave" value="Hrv">
    <input type="button" id="rus" class="zastave" value="Rus">
</div>
</nav>
Content of the page in En language
</div>

<div class="lng" id="de">
<nav>
<div id="lngSpace">
    Language Selector
    <input type="button" id="slo" class="zastave" value="Slo">
    <input type="button" id="ang" class="zastave" value="Eng">
    <input type="button" id="nem" class="zastave" value="Deu">
    <input type="button" id="ita" class="zastave" value="Ita">
    <input type="button" id="hrv" class="zastave" value="Hrv">
    <input type="button" id="rus" class="zastave" value="Rus">
</div>
</nav>
Content of the page in Ger language
</div>

etc etc

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** my code also contains this piece of JS which runs at the very start. I don't think it's effecting the rest of the JS, as I am trying to only change the display of divs and not reload the page... but just I'm posting it just in case (as the example posted to plnkr actually works...)

```
var language = navigator.language || navigator.languages[0];
console.log(language);
var languageFistTwo = language.substr(0,2); // To only keep the first 2 characters.
console.log(languageFistTwo);

switch (languageFistTwo) {
    case "sl":
        document.getElementById("sl").style.display="inline-block";
        break;  
    case "en":
        document.getElementById("en").style.display="inline-block";
        break;
    case "de":
        document.getElementById("de").style.display="inline-block";
        break;
    case "it":
        document.getElementById("it").style.display="inline-block";
        break;
    case "hr":
        document.getElementById("hr").style.display="inline-block";
        break;
    case "ru":
        document.getElementById("ru").style.display="inline-block";
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("en").style.display="inline-block";
        break;
}
```

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/FWsUfBzRp1yuS4WKDTIw?p=info

Comment: It doesn't make sense to repeat function with the same body and different names. Use `class` attribute instead and attach your click handler by class. To affect only specific target pass it as a parameter to your click handler. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769717/readmore-button-for-several-divs/59770024#59770024) for example.

Comment: Please provide a runable example. More than half of it is not defined (functions, classes). Instead of `document.getElementById("ru")` use `this` or a parameter and you can do all with one function since that is the only variable part.

Comment: don't know how to make it runable, sorry. added some content to the html so it makes some sense.

Comment: @DrDoom You can use something like https://plnkr.co/ to create a example of what you are trying to build. Something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/YiQDfqTdGKav8gJkv9FR?p=catalogue

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/FWsUfBzRp1yuS4WKDTIw?p=info

Comment: Okay, so what's the issue? :) Your code seems to work. You click a language and it shows the set language and you can switch between multiple languages.

Comment: exactly... it doesn't work in my actual html though... As stated it only works once. I have `input` set as `image` but that shouldn't be the reason why it's not working...

Comment: `It only works once`. Do you mean you can only select one language through a click? Do the buttons disappear? Is there a console log error? Also you're creating multiple functions for the same function. It's better to make an abstract function that uses a parameter for it's value. Much easier to maintain > https://plnkr.co/edit/7GS6XlMkrQBXngVit5bz?p=preview

Comment: If I click on ie. the german flag, it gives me the german content. After that when I click on ie. the english flag, nothing happens.

Comment: how is setLanguage working? I don't see any functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206153/discussion-between-peter-boomsma-and-drdoom).

Comment: I do not understand why you have clones of the language selectors, yet your `id` are not unique and thus merely the first set of buttons get the click-event assigned to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an edited example of what I assume you are trying to do. If you want to run with your example you have to use `class` on the buttons instead of `id` and a `click` listeners to all images and not just the first set.

Either way, you can solve all in one function. You do not need a function for each language.

Comments and explanations are in the code.

```js
//function toRu(){
function toAny(){
    var lngs = document.querySelectorAll(".lng");
    for (var i=0;i<lngs.length;i++){
        //REM: The element with the matching id is inline-block, the others none
        lngs[i].style.display = lngs[i].getAttribute('data-id') == this.value ? 'inline-block' : 'none'
    }
}

//REM: This only assings the event to one button
/*
document.getElementById("slo").addEventListener("click", toAny);
document.getElementById("ang").addEventListener("click", toAny);
document.getElementById("nem").addEventListener("click", toAny);
document.getElementById("ita").addEventListener("click", toAny);
document.getElementById("hrv").addEventListener("click", toAny);
document.getElementById("rus").addEventListener("click", toAny);
*/

for(var tL=document.querySelectorAll('input.zastave'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
  tL[i].addEventListener("click", toAny);
}
```

```html
<!--
I do not know why you replicated the language selectors multiple times. For me this structure makes more sense.
-->
<nav>
  <input type="button" id="slo" class="zastave" value="Slo">
  <input type="button" id="ang" class="zastave" value="Eng">
  <input type="button" id="nem" class="zastave" value="Deu">
  <input type="button" id="ita" class="zastave" value="Ita">
  <input type="button" id="hrv" class="zastave" value="Hrv">
  <input type="button" id="rus" class="zastave" value="Rus">
</nav>
<!--
id should be unique. Therefore I changed it to data-id and made it match the values of the buttons. This allows us to easily toggle the right divs in one function
-->
<div class="lng" data-id="Slo">
Content of the page in Sl language
</div>

<div class="lng" data-id="Eng">
Content of the page in En language
</div>

<div class="lng" data-id="Deu">
Content of the page in Ger language
</div>
```

Comment: this navigation actually has flags. on the real site there are redirect buttons to subpages in different languages.

Comment: The main issue on your approach is the reuse of the same `id` like posted in the comments. Yet, I do not know your "real site" :-)

Comment: join the discussion =) there is a link to the "real site" there. And yes, multiple IDs do occur... =/

Comment: I see it. It is fine, looks like Peter makes the same changes I made above. So I leave him to it :-)